# Windows 8 AdControl using HTML5

Tags: html, windows-store-apps, windows-store

I have a Windows 8 AdControl set-up in this way:

```
<div id="adControl" style="width: 728px; height: 90px; border: solid 1px red; visibility:visible;"
    data-win-control="MicrosoftNSJS.Advertising.AdControl"
    data-win-options="{applicationId: 'abc-1234', adUnitId: '12345'}">
</div>
```

I know the control is displaying because I can see a red line around it.  However, I'm not seeing any ads being rendered (the ad is registered).  I have the same control in a Metro app using XAML and I see the ads fine.

Is there an extra trick to ads using HTML5 that I've missing?

EDIT:

The SDK is included in the project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay - in the end I sussed this completely by accident.  An obvious mistake, but very difficult to spot with Javascript's "No errors" policy!  The problem was that I hadn't included the script:

```
<script src="/MSAdvertisingJS/ads/ad.js"></script>
```

I'd added the reference and it didn't occur to me that it needed this as well.

Answer (score 1):

The cause of problem comes from many difference things. Basically, there are some important details that you should follow up, especially the last bullet:

- You must specify a height and width for the `AdControl`. Failing to specify the Height and Width attributes, or setting them to auto, will cause tears of frustration. I'd recommend 80 pixels high and 480 pixels wide, as that's the native size of the ads that Microsoft serves up.
- It seems that you can't have two `AdControls` on the same page, or at least not in the same parent element. The second one will collapse. There might be a way around this, but I discovered it while building my demo app and didn't care to pursue a solution.
- You must must must specify certain capabilities in your `WMAppManifest.xml` file. Since I was upgrading my app, I didn't have some of the newer capabilities declared. The one that was causing all the trouble was `ID_CAP_IDENTITY_USER`. The following capabilities are all required for the control to function correctly:

  ```
  <Capabilities>
      <Capability Name="ID_CAP_IDENTITY_USER"/>
      <Capability Name="ID_CAP_MEDIALIB"/>
      <Capability Name="ID_CAP_NETWORKING"/>
      <Capability Name="ID_CAP_PHONEDIALER"/>
      <Capability Name="ID_CAP_WEBBROWSERCOMPONENT"/>
  </Capabilities>
  ```

[See more information here](http://whiletruecode.tumblr.com/tagged/Windows-Phone)

Comment: Thanks.  I suspect this may be true for Windows Phone, but this relates to a Windows 8 App, not a phone app.  The capability list looks different for a Win 8 app, and I don't believe there's an Identity User capability.

Comment: Do you have error handling built into your app?  If not, please follow the instructions [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/advertising-windows-examples-errorhandling(v=msads.10).aspx).

Comment: I didn't have.  I've just added that, but strangely, I don't get any error output at all.

Comment: It doesn't return some errors. Well, it is out of my abilities to help. You can send your issue to psupport@microsoft.com and include your account number, application ID, AdUnit ID, and the code snippet containing the AdControl. The microsoft team will help you as well.